# How add class the_content();?

Tags: posts, wp-query, the-content

How do I add a class `the_content();`?

```
<div class="csoporszoveg">
    <h3 class="csoporcim"><?php
        if ($settings['enable_link']) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post) . '">';
        }

        the_title();

        if ($settings['enable_link']) {
            echo '</a>';
        }
        ?>
    </h3>
    <?php } ?>  
      <?php
        if ( $content_source == 'excerpt' ) {
            the_excerpt();
        } else {
            the_content();
        }
      ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You'll need to put an element around it:

```
<?php if ( $content_source == 'excerpt' ) { ?>
    <div class="excerpt">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a paragraph? It can't be a paragraph because `the_content()` will contain paragraphs and you can't nest paragraphs. Use a `<div>`, or if it's semantically correct, a `<section>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
        if ( $content_source == 'excerpt' ) {
            the_excerpt();
        } else {
        ?>
            <div class="post_content"><?php the_content(); ?><div>
        <?php
        }
?>
```

Target `p` inside `div.post_content`

Comment: That will never work, because you are calling `the_content();` outside of the PHP scope.

Answer (score -3):

Like this:

```
<p class="description"><?php echo  get_the_content();?></p>
```

Comment: What if your content has more than 1 paragraph or needs to display embeds? This is not the proper way to display content.

Comment: I would wrap it in a div tag, not a p tag. =)